# Downloading an XML file using angularJs resource

Tags: angularjs, download, angular-resource, ngresource

I'm trying to use angularJs resource to download a file from a server but it dosen't work.
my code is as following:

```
// service
angular.module("someModule")
.factory('generate', ['$resource', '$rootScope', function ($resource, $rootScope) {
return $resource('some url...');}]);


//Js controller file - I'm getting the 'generate' service in the head of the controller
 $scope.$on('generateFile', function(){
    generate.get();
});


//html
<a ng-click="$emit('generateFile')"></a>
```

When i'm typing the url it download the file - so the server side is fine. However, I couldn't find any example of using angular resource to download a file.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you post the content of that file as an example? Using JSON with $resource is quite straightforward, but using XML seems not that easy. You might be better of using $http, and parse the data manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [downloading files from nodejs using angular at client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652927/downloading-files-from-nodejs-using-angular-at-client-side)

Answer (score 0):

Use an interceptor to grab the responseXML:

```
function grabResponseXML($q, dependency1, dependency2) 
    {
    return {
           'response': function(response) 
              {
              var deferred = $q.defer();

              if (response.headers()['content-type'] === 'text/xml; charset="UTF-8"') 
                {
                localStorage.setItem('xmlResponse', response.responseXML);
                }
              deferred.resolve(response);

              return deferred.promise;
              }
           }
    }             

$httpProvider.interceptors.push(grabResponseXML);
```

**References**

- [ngSharePoint.js - SharePointInterceptor](https://github.com/hemrika/SharePoint_Client/blob/master/www/lib/SharePoint/ngSharePoint.js#L67)
- [httpSpec.js: 'should pass in the response object when a request is successful'](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/httpSpec.js#L413)
- [Content Disposition Values and Parameters](http://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml)
- [How To Raise a "File Download" Dialog Box for a Known MIME Type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/260519)
- [angular.js issue #6860: angular directive templateUrl should allow "text/html" Accept and content-type headers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6860)