# downloading files from nodejs using angular at client side

Tags: node.js, angularjs, download, route-provider

I have a simple angular app which has configuration like -

```
angular.module('app',['ngResource','ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','angularFileUpload']);

angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);        
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: '/partials/main/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'})
        .when('/browse/notes', { templateUrl: '/partials/notes/browseNotes',
            controller: 'browseNotesCtrl'
        })
        .when('/upload/notes', { templateUrl: '/partials/notes/uploadNotes',
            controller: 'uploadNotesCtrl'
        })
        .when('/profile',{ templateUrl:'/partials/account/mvProfile',
            controller: 'mvProfileCtrl' 
        }).when('/browse/notes/:noteId',{ templateUrl:'/partials/notes/noteDetail',
            controller: 'mvNoteDetailsCtrl' 
        });
});
```

Now, my noteDetail partial has content -

```
ol
    li(ng-repeat="n in range(note.actualFileName.length)")
    a(ng-click="download(n)") {{note.actualFileName[n]}}
```

and controller has code -

```
$scope.download = function(n){
        console.log(n);
        var downloadUrl = '/download/note/' + $scope.note.noteId + '/' + $scope.note.storedFileName[n];
        $http({method:'GET',url:downloadUrl}).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

and my server side route configuration in nodejs is as follows -

```
app.get('/download/note/:noteid/:fileid',notes.download);
```

and notes.download has

```
exports.download = function(req,res) {
    console.log("here");
    console.log(req.params.noteid);
    console.log(req.params.fileid);
    res.status(200);
    var filepath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../../');
    filepath += 'server/uploads/' + req.params.fileid;
    console.log(filepath);
    res.download(filepath,'server.pdf');
};
```

now the problem here is if i open some url like -

```
http://localhost:5000/download/note/9281a9d1-1b51-4e1b-9102-2b422cb2a111/e3ec261b-4722-4a69-ada6-68f88e2ff3db.pdf
```

directly in the browser it downloads the new file
but if i open it from the $http obviously it logs the encrypted binary data into the console, instead of downloading it. So, how do i achieve this?

and also, even if i create an anchor tag with something like -

[image: beforeClick]

and then after i click it opens an page without any template ( as i don't have any template defined for this route in my routeProvider configuration, indicating that the route passes through the routeProvider which does not forward it to the server, i feel ) 
here is what i see after clicking on attachment - 
[image]
but if i open it in new tab request goes to server and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't save files using ajax, unless you're willing to rebuild the file on the client's side using blobs. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682556/why-threre-is-no-way-to-download-file-using-ajax-request)

Just use something like

```
$location.url('/download/note/' + $scope.note.noteId + '/' + $scope.note.storedFileName[n]);
```

As for the second part, your routeProvider doesn't know what to do when the path is invalid. Add

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/main/main',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/browse/notes', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/notes/browseNotes',
        controller: 'browseNotesCtrl'
    })
    .when('/upload/notes', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/notes/uploadNotes',
        controller: 'uploadNotesCtrl'
    })
    .when('/profile', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/account/mvProfile',
        controller: 'mvProfileCtrl'
    })
    .when('/browse/notes/:noteId', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/notes/noteDetail',
        controller: 'mvNoteDetailsCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/wherever'
    });
```

Comment: I understood that and a temporary work around was to use target=_blank property and give the url there itself, but my main concern is the second part of my question for why the angular(routeProvider) tries to load a template url for a route which is not specified by me and let the request go to server

Comment: `target="_self"` may be better. Updated the question.

Comment: Also, JS has no access to the filesystem to store your file.

Comment: so, what should i add to the routeProvider configuration so that it simply passes whatever invalid path it received to the server, since here in what you told: /whatever is a static single route and I have more than one route here for the server. thanks for _self too does work

Comment: also i tried adding this path - .when('/download/note/:noteId/:fileId',{ redirectTo:'/download/note/:noteId/:fileId'
        }) to the routeProvider but it too took the app to the page shown in the afterClick and showed me an empty page without any template url

Comment: It needs to be on it's own. Otherwise takes anyone route that's not in the when chain. Edited the question again to show what it should look like. You should probably set it to a 404 page or the application root `/`.